# Gas cooker makes a weird noise sometimes

Tags: gas-burner

Every once in a while, my gas cooker starts making a weird cracking noise. It only happens sometimes (rarely) and only on one of the burners. If I turn the burner off and on again, sometimes it goes away and fixes itself, but sometimes it comes back soon after.

I've tried replacing the black cap but it didn't fix the problem.

Video here: https://mega.nz/file/fJYUSLJJ#X5FGgYWfKg0sWjjnMzzS472BkNqEtFGchdYtdXgLngM

Comment: Brand & model of the cooker? Please [edit] that into your question. Also, where in the world are you located?

Comment: What is the "black cap"